# BULK API -PK Chunking Header Query - job content type : application/xml

Tags: bulk-api

Is it possible to use PK Chunking Header for a Query job of type XML. It works with CSV and when i pass it for xml jobs it fails and gives this error

> InternalServerError : PKChunking failed. InvalidBatch : Wrong content-type for batch (text/csv), job is of type: application/xml.

The Salesforce site gives examples with content-type : text/csv or application/xml.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is a known issue: [Bulk API with PK Chunking enabled throws ISE if contentType is application/xml, add support for application/xml](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZL6AAM)

> **Summary**
>   Bulk API query jobs with PK Chunking header fail, if the contentType is application/xml.
>
> Error Message:
>   PKChunking failed. InvalidBatch : Wrong content-type for batch (text/csv), job is of type: application/xml "
>
> ...
>
> **Workaround**
>   Set content-type for batch as text/csv